# Set Width of HTML element at runtime in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to set the width of an HTML element at runtime from my controller in AngularJS. My controller is defined within my directive. I know that I need to set the width of the first `ul` element within the directive. Currently, I have the following:

```
var list = $element.find('ul');
$element(list[0]).css('width', '300px'));
```

However, when I try this, I get an error that says:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I set the width of an HTML element at runtime in AngularJS?

Thank you!

Comment: Modifying DOM elements inside a controller isn't a great idea. If you need to do that, use the `link` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need JQuery to do what you want, AngularJS has **jqlite**. As mentioned in the **[AngularJS Developer's Guide for directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom)**:

> **element** is the **jqLite**-wrapped element that this directive matches.

So it should be able to do most of the features that jQuery is capable of, as defined in the **[`angular.element()` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)**.

What the documentation fails to define, is that the jqlite version for finding elements returns an array of HTML elements. So you have to use `angular.element()` on each element that you want to manipulate inside that array using the jqlite functionalities. So the code should generally look like this:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1yyL3vp1/2/)**

```
   var list = elem.find('ul');
   angular.element(list[0]).css('width', '300px');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use $element like its a function.

```
var list = $element.find('ul');
list[0].css('width', '300px');
```

or in one line:

```
$element.find('ul')[0].css('width', '300px');
```

Comment: Oddly, when I try that I get an error that says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined`. If I do a `console.log($element.find('ul')[0]);` I see `[ready: function, toString: function, eq: function, push: function, sort: function…` in the console window.

Comment: You need to add the full jquery library to use all jquery functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a bit to Brian's answer.

$element. functions differently depending on whether or not jquery is available, because it is a jquery selector. If jquery is available, it will represent a jquery element, if not it will use the jqlite built into angular.

That said, I think the equivalent of your implementation in jquery is something like:

```
var list = $('ul')
$(list[0]).css('width','300px');
```

or

```
$($('ul')[0]).css
```

Which doesn't look right to me. Brians answer can be converted to jquery succinctly, yours cannot.